# Difference between different and does not belong to?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

I know this is a dumb question but...

Is $x ≠ 1,3,5$ the same as $x$ does not belong to {$1,3,5$}, for example ?

---

Sorry for the formatting.

Btw, anyone has a link with mathjax's commands I guess?

---

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to make the lack of belonging more explicit, you can use the symbol $\notin$: $x \notin \{1,3,5\}$.

Comment: For MathJax, see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the set notation has benefits of its own. For eg. once you define how to want an arbitrary set $S$ to look like, the name $S$ becomes an alias for that definition forever. So, you are saved from a ton of writing by referring to $S$ only and not individually to its elements.

So, while writing a proof, instead of writing and rewriting $x\ne1$ and $x\ne2$ and $x\ne3$, you can just write $x\notin S$ where $S=\{1,2,3\}$ and you are done. More over, you can't just give commas in between as in the question. One good reason for that is because the operations "logical-and" & "logical-or" are not conveyed very properly by the comma notation.

Note: Refer to the comment by @Erick Wong in the comments below. This provides another valid perspective.

Comment: On the other hand, set notation doesn’t extend well to more general equivalence relations.  For that reason you tend to see people write $p\not\equiv 1,3 \pmod 8$, as the convenience trumps the abuse of notation.

Answer (score 1):

$x \neq 1, 3, 5$ isn't super standard notation, but if someone wrote it out at random I'd assume they meant $x \neq 1$ and $x \neq 3$ and $x \neq 5,$ or $x \not\in \{1, 3, 5\}$ for short.

Comment: In this case, x≠1 and x≠3 and x≠5 would be the same as x∉{1,3,5}, correct?

Comment: @San, yes, that is what $\notin$ means: $x$ is not equal to any of the elements of the set.

Answer (score -1):

$x\notin (1,3,5)$ means that $x$ is not a member of a set.  The set is defined as elements, which could be letters, intervals or anything else.  $x\ne 1$, etc.  means that equality is defined which is no necessarily true, unless equality is defined by identity.

Simple example $1+2=3$, but for set membership $\{1+2\}$ is not the same as $\{3\}$.

Comment: Could you provide a concrete example of a context where equality isn’t defined, but inclusion is?  When $x$ is an interval I think I’d be okay with saying $x \ne 1$.  It would sound a bit frivolous, but no more so than $x \notin \{1\}$.

Comment: @ErickWong  I have added an example of the distinction I was trying to make.